# Include a form of a certain controller in the index page in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I want to add a form of a certain controller (_form.php) in the index page. My controller is called AgreedController and the form has some text fields and 2 dropDownList.

How to partially draw this form in the index page?

Edit:
I was able to display the form with this piece of code

```
$model = new Agreed;
$controller = Yii::app() ->createController('agreed');
$agreedController = $controller[0];
$agreedController->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model));
```

But my problem now is that when the submit button is pressed, no action executed.
How to call the actionCreate() with this code to perform the actual insertion in the database?
Thanks.

Comment: What's your mean؟ Please explain more clearly.

Comment: I have added some piece of code to explain more. now i need when the submit button is pressed the actionCreate() is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Edit:** I not understand why you used this way, but if you need call an **controller/action** from other place, you can do like following: you can define **$model** variable in **controller/action** destination:

```
$controller = Yii::app() ->createController('agreed'); 
$agreedController = $controller[0];
agreedController->run('actionName');
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Yii::app() ->createController('agreed'); 
this returns an array, and i need the first element of it which contains the controller.